# Testing angular controller in Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Me and my team have been having a problem setting up a controller test with the Karma test runner on Jasmine.

> **app/app.js**

```
buyItApp = angular.module('buyItApp', ['ionic']);
```

> **app/controllers/userSearchCtrl.js**

```
buyItApp.controller("userSearchCtrl", function($http, $scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.searchQuery = function(searchData) {
    $( "ion-spinner").toggle(true);
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://productfeedtest.wandoso.com/?keyword=' + searchData
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $( "ion-spinner").toggle(false);
      $scope.showResultsCount = true
      $scope.items = response.data.items;
      $scope.isOffer = response.data.is_special_offer;
      $scope.resultsCount = response.data.items.length;
      $scope.searchQuery = searchData;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.searchResults = "server error!"
    });
  }
});
```

> **test/karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-mocks.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-scenario.js',
      '../public/javascripts/app/*.js',
      '../public/javascripts/app/controllers/*.js',
      'unit/userSearchCtrl.spec.js',
      'unit/*.spec.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

> **test/unit/userSearchCtrl.spec.js**

```
describe('userSearchCtrl', function() {

    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, userSearchCtrl;

    beforeEach(module('buyItApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;

        userSearchCtrl = $controller('userSearchCtrl', {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $scope});
    }));

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(userSearchCtrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

> **The failing test result**

http://textuploader.com/5jo6b

Most notably:

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
        at /Users/Harry/Dropbox/Dev/buyIt/test/unit/userSearchCtrl.spec.js:16
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

It looks like Karma cannot find the controller, however after checking the code and reviewing other projects it is not so clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error

```
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=buyItApp&p1=Error:
> [$injector:modulerr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=ionic&p1=Error:
> [$injector:nomod]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ionic
```

explicitly says, it can't find `ionic` module which is loaded in `buyItApp`. Because it wasn't included in Karma `files`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the issue (removing ionic from my app passes the test) - if you have any idea of where to inject Ionic in userSearchCtrl.spec.js, I would be grateful if you could provide a hint, I am new to testing angular.

Comment: @Stussy If you don't need 'ionic' dependency in controllers, the common recipe is to have e.g. 'buyItApp.controllers' module to test it separately, so 'buyItApp' loads ['buyItApp.controllers', 'ionic'] .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't use mocks.

`beforeEach(module('buyItApp'));` is afaik instantiating a real module. This obviously fails since you don't include the dependencies.

Also if you want to mock functionality of the controller you should use `angular.mock.inject` instead of just `inject`.

I'm not sure about this, but I have been always doing it like this.

Your specs would look like this then:

```
describe('userSearchCtrl', function() {
    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, userSearchCtrl;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('buyItApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;

        userSearchCtrl = $controller(
            'userSearchCtrl', 
            {
                '$rootScope' : $rootScope, 
                '$scope': $scope
            }
        );
   }));

   it('should exist', function() {
       expect(userSearchCtrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, if you have a full example of a .spec.js that you could share it would be very helpful

Comment: Updated my answer with your specs modified.

Comment: It is ok to use 'inject', using 'angular.mock.module' is encouraged because of possible name collision with commonjs 'module'.

Comment: I see, I also saw the issue mentioned in the answer above - I totally missed that. I think this is the second thing you are missing. Still I'd go for the using the mock explicitly to avoid any "noise" by the framework.

Comment: Yes the above has worked combined with the code of @FlorianTopf - lesson learned - read the stack. But the issue remains of where to inject the ionic dependency into the mock?